# Image vertical height in absolute div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create my own lightbox, and now i am stuck on design part, i've manager to create slide box with horizontal responsive image as i want

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="centerer"></span>
        <div>
            <img src="http://images.car.bauercdn.com/pagefiles/18474/bmw_7-series_05.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="arrow left" href="#">
        <span class="centerer"></span>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GbeQojB.png" />
    </a>
    <a class="arrow right" href="#">
        <span class="centerer"></span>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GbeQojB.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

_

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.gallery {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #333;
}

.container {
  width:80%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.container div {
  display:inline-block;
  width:95%;
}

.centerer {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.arrow {
  width:10%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

.arrow img {
  display:inline-block;
  opacity:0.5;
  width:50%;
}

.arrow:hover img {
  opacity:1;
}

.arrow.left {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  left:0;
}

.arrow.right {
  right:0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4zpk43f2/

, but when i use it with vertical photo, it ... sucks. 
I've tried to change some display settings, but it's or good for vertical, or good for horizontal.

https://jsfiddle.net/d470vkc9/1/

Comment: Please explain how it `sucks` and `it's or good for vertical, or good for horizontal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you limited the width of the image to `80%` by applying `width: 80%` to the `.container`. and you gave `height: 100%` to the same. That is why the image was stretching to full, vertically. Mention height also as `80%` as you did to the `.container`.

Try this:

```
.container {
    height: 80%;
    top: 10%;
    /* other styles */
}

.container > div {
    height: 100%;  /* or less as you prefer */
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d470vkc9/2/)**